# How to check the value of a field in a linked table?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, organisations and opportunities, linked by a one-to-many relationship on the organisation ID. The opportunity table contains a flag `is_active`, value either 0 or 1.

I want to determine whether any given organisation has any active opportunities.

I've written this in mySQL:

```
SELECT orgreg.orgreg_id AS id, orgreg.name AS name, 
  orgreg.doit_uuid As uuid, SUM(oppreg.is_active) AS active
FROM orgreg 
INNER JOIN oppreg ON orgreg.orgreg_id = oppreg.orgreg_id
GROUP BY orgreg.orgreg_id 
ORDER BY orgreg.name ASC
```

If `active` is greater than zero, at least one opportunity is active, which is what I want to test.

However, if the organisation has no opportunities, a result is not returned.

EDIT

Can members suggest a better way of answering the original question that lists *all* organisations with an `active` element that is either 0 or 1, 0 if there are no opportunities or they are all inactive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer I've come up with, which only needs a change of JOIN type and the adding of a IF statement to my original code to give me what I need. Without the IF statement it will return three possible answers, NULL if no opportunities, 0 if no active opportunities, or the number of active opportunities.

```
SELECT orgreg.orgreg_id AS id, orgreg.name AS name, 
    orgreg.doit_uuid As uuid, if(sum(oppreg.is_active), 1, 0) AS total 
FROM orgreg 
LEFT OUTER JOIN oppreg ON orgreg.orgreg_id = oppreg.orgreg_id 
GROUP BY orgreg.orgreg_id ORDER BY orgreg.name ASC
```

If anyone can simplify this, I'd be glad to hear.

Comment: Create a fiddle with sample data here: https://www.db-fiddle.com just to check your code and results.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to join the tables or aggregation if you want to check *whether any given organisation has any active opportunities*.
You can do it with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT o.orgreg_id AS id, o.name AS name, 
       o.doit_uuid As uuid, 
       EXISTS(
         SELECT 1 FROM oppreg p
         WHERE p.orgreg_id = o.orgreg_id AND p.is_active
       ) AS active
FROM orgreg o
```

Comment: Many thanks for introducing me to the EXISTS keyword. When I put this into the mySQL console, it flagged up several errors. But it does run OK. However, it returns 0 in the "active" field if the organisation has no opportunities at all and 1 if it has at least one, whether any are active or not, which isn't the answer I need.

Comment: *and 1 if it has at least one, whether any are active or not* no it does not do that. This condition: `AND p.is_active` guarantees that only if there is at least 1 active then the result will be 1.

Comment: It seems that my version of mySQL is different to yours. I agree that looks as though it ought to be the response. I've found that if I modify your query to "AND p.is_active = 1" then I get the answer I need in the mySQL console. But if I then put exactly the same code into an SQL query in PHP, the data comes back with the "active" field always set to 1. That seems more than a little bizarre. Any thoughts?

Comment: MySql considers any integer value = 0 as false and any value <> 0 as true in any version. So there is no difference between `AND p.is_active` and `AND p.is_active = 1`. I guess that you don't use my code exactly as it is.

Comment: That has always been my understanding, so was surprised when it seemed to work. I assure you that I am otherwise using your code exactly as you typed it by copying and pasting it into mySQL.